# Android ImageView doesn't change size after image set

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have problem with setting new image on ImageView.

My xml looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_border" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImageIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</FrameLayout>
```

ImageView has no image set.
In code after some user action I set image to ImageView:

```
ivImageIcon.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
```

Problem is that image is not visible because ImageView doesn't change it's size (border of FrameLayout stays the same). I tried to use:

```
ivImageIcon.invalidate();
```

but nothing changes.

If I set layout_width and layout_height in xml to specific value image is visible. Also tried to set LayoutParams to ImageView after I set image but not working either (height doesn't change).

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Any specific reason for using framelayout?

Comment: @Manikanta, no, it may be other ViewGroup, I just want to add background.

Comment: change frame layout to relative layout,  remove viewbounds and scaletype property , try setting image drawable to imageview(i guess you might be converting image from drawable to bitmap).

Comment: These are wild guesses unless you post code i cant nail your problem

Comment: @manikanta, I changed to Relative Layout and removed viewBounds and scaleType and it's not working. I have Bitmap created in my code not from drawable (bitmap is ok because when I set layout_width and layout_height in xml it shows in ImageView). What code you want me to post, relevant part is in my post.

Comment: add this dependency to your gradle ,   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'  ,  load bitmap into image view like this Picasso.with(context).load(bitmap).into(imageView);

Comment: for (What code you want me to post, relevant part is in my post)  i dont know if the dynamic bitmap you are creating is correct.

Comment: did you gave it a try?

Comment: you are using layout_width as wrap_content for both, the layout and imageview and then you are using fit_center in imageview. This is wrong. How will the the system know, in how much area, do you have to centre the image? Try using match_parent and then use scale property, or use wrap_parent and do not set the scaletype.